# What does the "p" in strptime stand for?

Tags: strptime

There is a `strptime` function in many language libraries (C, Python, Ruby, PHP, PERL, etc.).

It seems to be based on the [Open Group's specification for `time.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html).

I understand 'str' stands for string, and 'time' obviously stands for time, but what does the 'p' stand for? Parse? Pointer? Print?

*Every time I reach for the strptime() function, I have a mental blank, and have to look up the name in a manual. I figure if I finally worked out what it stood for, perhaps I would have a chance of remembering it.*

Comment: stands for parse... string parse time

Comment: @Nile - So, how do you know that?

Comment: I mean... does it really matter? Whatever you want to think of it as, parse, pointer, print... it could even stand for `POSIX`. Who knows what those guys were thinking.

Comment: I think I explained my justification in the question. Further, if there *is* a good reason, it may help my understanding of other code, or even persuade me to adopt the standard...

Comment: I mean, obviously you want a way to remember it. But if you just think of it as "string posix time" or "string pointer time" or "string parse time", it'll work....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

p = pointer. [It returns](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) a pointer to a char.

BTW According to my K&R there is a

```
char *strpbrk(cs,ct);
```

This 'p' also refers to the returned pointer.

Comment: if the p in `strptime` would refer to _pointer_ then I guess the f in `strftime` refers to _from pointer_? That seems unlikely.

Comment: `strptime` = str points to time = str -> time. `strftime` = str from time = str <- time.

Comment: In Python is clear. `d1 = datetime.strptime('2019-12-25', '%Y:%m:%d')  # str, parse, time. This creates a datetime object from a string`. And `d1.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')` formats the datetime as a string.

Comment: @KenT 's comment above should be the answer.

Answer (score 26):

I guess it stands for "parse" because its reverse function is called `strftime` in Python's [`time`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) module wherein the "f" I can reasonably guess stands for "format".

Comment: I would like to say **f** stands for **from**. So that I always remember _strftime_ gives me a string **from** a datetime object. But I like your "parse" idea for strptime :)

Answer (score 9):

Most of the places, I found

> strftime() -> string format time & 
>   strptime() -> string parsed time

Comment: Can you please give some examples?

Comment: In docs from source code of Python method `strptime` it shows this: `new datetime parsed from a string`

Answer (score 7):

I have same problem and I'm going with put:

```
strftime -> 'string from time'
strptime -> 'string, put time'
```

Answer (score 6):

It helps me to remember:

- **p** for **produce**, str p time -> string **produce** time
- **f** for **format**,  str f time -> string **format** time

Answer (score 0):

I think of `strftime()` as string from time. And the function `strptime()` is, probably, derived from string parsed time.

Answer (score -1):

This is yet another way to remember this:

f for from, str f time (strftime)-> string from time

p for produce, str p time (strptime)-> string produces time

Answer (score -1):

str**f**time: **format** a datetime into a string
str**p**time: **parse** a string into a datetime

Answer (score -1):

My mnemonic for your reference:

`strptime` = str points to time = str -> time.

`strftime` = str from time = str <- time.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a pneumonic I found helpful:

`strftime` -> string (**f**orward) **time** : this function converts from a **time** object

`strptime` -> **string** (**p**revious) time : this function converts from a **string** object